# how to display selectedinput to plot title for shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
  output$selected <- renderText({
    paste(input$name)
  })
  
  output$hcontainer8 <- renderHighchart({
    var <- textOutput("selected")
    hc2 <- df_clean %>% filter(df_clean$ManagerName == input$name)
    hchart(hc2, "lollipop", hcaes(name = Employee_Name, low = Absences ),name = "Absences") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>% 
      hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value}")) %>% 
      hc_title(text="Employee Absences under {var}",align="center") %>% 
      hc_subtitle(text = "with mean value from each department group by Performance Score", align = "center")
  })
```

so this is my code for the server.r and I want to show the manager name in the plot title
based on the selected input

```
(text="Employee Absences under {var}",align="center")
```

this is a closer look at the code, so I want to display it in {var} is there a way to do it?

Comment: not sure why you need `var`.. Just use `...hc_title(text = paste0("Employee Absences under ", input$name), align="center") %>%...`

Comment: Nesting `reactive`s is just a recipe for disaster.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input$name` is a string that you can use to both `filter` and within the `hc_title()` call.

Try:

```
hc_title(text = paste0("Employee Absences under ", input$name), align="center") %>%
```